# Merge tags [webdeploy] and [microsoft-web-deploy] on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

[webdeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdeploy) and [microsoft-web-deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-web-deploy) seem like duplicates.

Can they be merged so that [microsoft-web-deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-web-deploy) is a synonym of [webdeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdeploy)?

(Approved voters can support the proposal by upvoting at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/webdeploy/synonyms)

Comment: Would it not make more sense to make [webdeploy] the synonym?

Comment: I went with the larger question pool being the more dominant tag, but not fussy personally.

Comment: Yes, that does indeed make sense in terms of workload.

Comment: webdeploy seems to have the larger question pool and the better tag description

Comment: [Meta rant:] Gaaah. Every synonym request I ever see, there are people talking about whether X should be a synonym of Y or instead Y should be a synonym of X. What does it *mean*? In normal English, "is a synonym of" is a symmetric relation, and the relevant tag wikis on Meta don't establish what's meant by each direction. If I go to the `foo` tag and type `bar` into the "Suggest a `foo` synonym" box, have I, in the terminology of Meta, made `foo` a synonym of `bar` or `bar` a synonym of `foo`? I have no idea. Can we not, as a community, manage to come up with some less confusing terminology?

Comment: Seems like [tag:microsoft-web-deploy] would be a `subset` of [tag:webdeploy]. @MarkAmery is `subset` a better, more directional word?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint It's not better, it is plagiarised from the link at the bottom of the description.

Comment: @Luuklag ah, I didn't bother clicking the link

Comment: @Pureferret That terminology certainly conveys a directional relationship, but it's not an accurate description of the relationship between synonymised tags. If X is a "subset" of Y, I'd expect that X is a topic that is contained within Y - e.g. X=`jquery` and Y=`javascript`, or X=`python3.x` and Y=`python`. That's not what the synonym relationship means, though.

Comment: @MarkAmery the bottom line of my suggestion is if I type [tag:microsoft-web-deploy] and get [tag:webdeploy] I'm happier than if I typed [tag:webdeploy] and got [tag:microsoft-web-deploy]

Comment: @Pureferret Why? Surely it ought to be the other way round, if anything - since typing webdeploy and getting microsoft-web-deploy assures you that the tag really does refer to the thing you think it does, and not some other webdeploy you've never heard of.

Comment: @MarkAmery if I want [tag:someother-webdeploy] so I type [tag:webdeploy] thinking it's a synonym, and I get [tag:microsoft-web-deploy]...that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Pureferret If you want someother-webdeploy, it's a *good* thing if microsoft-web-deploy comes up when you type webdeploy, because otherwise you'd be at risk of *wrongly* using the webdeploy tag, whose wiki currently states that's it's specifically about the tool from Microsoft.